# How to fix "502 Bad Gateway" NGINX error inside Docker container

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx

I need help from someone who understands Docker as I am new to Docker and trying to create a Dockerfile for WordPress, NGINX, and PHP. However, I encountered a "502 Bad Gateway" issue, even after fixing the configuration in nginx.conf. Thank you.

Dockerfile

```
# Base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Install NGINX
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx

# Install PHP and required extensions
RUN apt-get install -y php-fpm php-mysql

# Install WordPress
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf latest.tar.gz -C /var/www/html
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress

# Copy NGINX configuration
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start NGINX and PHP-FPM
CMD service php7.4-fpm start && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name localhost;

        root /var/www/html/wordpress;
        index index.php;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have missed to provide the error log. Regardless Docker or not, if you get a 5xx from the webserver, that is always an invitation to visit the error log.